# Unable to cast POINT datatype in INSERT query to PostgreSQL. Longitude, Latitude required to be inserted into table

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2, point

I'm trying to insert latitude & longitude that are stored as python variables into a table in PostgreSQL via the INSERT query. Any suggestions on how to cast Point other than what I've tried?

I tried the insert query first as shown -

This is the table:

```
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE AccidentList (
        accidentId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        cameraGeoLocation POINT,
        accidentTimeStamp TIMESTAMPTZ);''')
```

Try1:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO AccidentList(cameraGeoLocation,accidentTimeStamp)
VALUES {}".format((lat,lon),ts));
```

Error:

### >Hint: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "camerageolocation" is of type point but expression is of type numeric

> LINE 1: ...ist (cameraGeoLocation,accidentTimeStamp) VALUES (13.0843, 8...
>                                                                ^
>
> ### HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Try2:

```
query = "INSERT INTO AccidentList (cameraGeoLocation,accidentTimeStamp)
VALUES(cameraGeoLocation::POINT, accidentTimeStamp::TIMESTAMPTZ);"
data = ((lat,lon),ts)
cur.execute(query,data)
```

Error:

> LINE 1: ...List (cameraGeoLocation,accidentTimeStamp) VALUES(cameraGeoL...
>                                                                ^
>
> ### HINT:  There is a column named "camerageolocation" in table "accidentlist", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Try 3:

```
query = "INSERT INTO AccidentList (camerageolocation ,accidenttimestamp) VALUES(%s::POINT, %s);"
    data = (POINT(lat,lon),ts)
    cur.execute(query,data)
```

Error:

> cur.execute(query,data)
>   psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type record to point
>   LINE 1: ...tion ,accidenttimestamp) VALUES((13.0843, 80.2805)::POINT, '...

Answer (score 1):

Single quote your third attempt.
This works: `SELECT '(13.0843, 80.2805)'::POINT`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to insert data of type point into Postgres.
Using quotes around the tuple (making it a string) worked for me.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.autocommit = True
sql = 'insert into cities (name,location) values (%s,%s);'
values = ('City A','(10.,20.)')
cursor.execute(sql,values)
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

My environment:
PostgreSQL 12.4,
Python 3.7.2,
psycopg2-binary 2.8.5